# Do you know how to make the system automatically restart daemon service?

Tags: linux, process, systemd, start-stop-daemon

I have made a daemon service in linux server. It is running well. The service file is
stargate.service (in /etc/systemd/system).

```
[Unit]
Description=stargate

[Service]
Type=simple
PIDFile=/app/stargate/stargate.pid
ExecStart=/app/stargate/stargate.sh start
ExecReload=/app/stargate/stargate.sh restart
ExecStop=/app/stargate/stargate.sh stop

[Install]
Alias=stargate
WantedBy=default.target
```

If by some reasons, the daemon service is die and stop. Do you know how to make the system automatically restart the daemon service ?
How to make the daemon service starts if server get rebooted?

Comment: Surely you can find it. Search on google for `systemd.service` documentation and search for the word `restart` in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To respawn your service when it fails, add the following to the `[Service]` block:

```
[Service]
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=3
```

If you wish to always restart when your service is killed use `Restart=always`

The `RestartSec` value is the delay between restart attempts.

See more info here: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html